# Incr Tcl Objects in List/Array/Dict

Tags: tcl, incr-tcl

I'm trying to create a number of objects using itcl and then store them in a data structure so that i can invoke their methods later. But it is giving an error:

The following is the code i have written:

```
    itcl::class router {
        variable name;
        variable mac;
        variable interface_list;
        variable topology;

        constructor {rname rmac rtopology} {
            puts "creating new router $rname / $rmac within [$rtopology get_name]"
            set name $rname;
            set mac $rmac;
            set topology $rtopology;
        }

        destructor {
            delete $this;
        }

        method add_interface {name network_id} {
            set int [interface #auto $name $network_id $this];
            lappend interface_list $int;
        }

        method get_interfaces {} {
            return $interface_list;
        }

        method get_name{} {
            return $name;
        }

        method get_mac{} {
            return $mac;
        }

        method get_topology {} {
            return $topology;
        }
    }

    itcl::class topology {
        variable name;
        variable router_list;

        constructor {tname} {
            set name $tname;
            set router_list [dict create];
        }

        method add_router {name mac} {
            set newrouter [router #auto $name $mac $this];
            dict set router_list $name $newrouter;
        }

        method add_routerinterface {rname iname networkid} {
            foreach r [dict keys $router_list] {
                if {[$r get_name] == rname} {
                    $r add_interface $iname $networkid;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        method get_name {} {
            return $name;
        }

        method get_routers {} {
            return $router_list;
        }

        method show {} {
            foreach rkey $router_list {
                set router [dict get $router_list $rkey];
                set rname [$router get_name];
            }
        }
    }



topology t "JitixNet";
t add_router R1 fwe2165;
t add_router R2 dagsyu2;
t add_router R3 fasdjg3;

t show;
```

The error is as follows:

```
D:\Tcl\code>tclsh network-topology.tcl
creating new router R1 / fwe2165 within JitixNet
creating new router R2 / dagsyu2 within JitixNet
creating new router R3 / fasdjg3 within JitixNet
bad option "get_name": should be one of...
  router0 add_interface name network_id
  router0 cget -option
  router0 configure ?-option? ?value -option value...?
  router0 get_interfaces
  router0 get_mac{} return $mac;
  router0 get_name{} return $name;
  router0 get_topology
  router0 isa className
    while executing
"$router get_name"
    (object "::t" method "::topology::show" body line 4)
    invoked from within
"t show"
    (file "network-topology.tcl" line 142)
```

Can somebody please help? I'm at my wit's end... Frankly i was expecting ITcl to be something similar to Java...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you need to put a space between the method names and the (empty) parameter list. This is normal for commands in Tcl (you'd have to do the same if declaring a standard Tcl procedure).

### Guide to diagnosis

If you look at the error message, you can see that one of the "allowed ways of calling it" is:

```
 get_name{} return $name;
```

That's a *very* odd name and a distinctly odd set of parameters too. A quick glance at the code confirms the lack of a space. (It's not an error because of peculiarities in how ITcl handles partial declarations. I don't particularly care for that, but that's getting off-topic…)

Comment: In general, read the whole error message. That's usually very informative in Tcl…

Comment: Thanks a lot Donal! Your Answer was very helpful.. :)
I've been struggling with the spacing and the $ sign on tcl a lot....

Comment: @Jit Your problem is almost certainly that you're used to how it works in some other languages. In Tcl, `$` means “read a variable, now” and everything is initially parsed into words which are separated by spaces (those words being the names of commands and arguments to them). There's very little magic beyond that, at least at the parsing level; Tcl's got very little magic there. (Some of the standard commands have a high magic quotient, but you can always figure out exactly what you're passing into them.)